# Matrix Implemention in R

Tags: r, matrix

I'm trying to implement a matrix into R based on the following formula:

```
A = matrix( c(), nrow=, ncol=, byrow=TRUE)
```

So based on the formula I insert the data , the number of rows and columns.
The problem is that when the ENTER BUTTON is pressed, no `<` symbol appears but `+` symbol appears.

Can anyone tell me the meaning of this? The data I use corresponds to the number of rows and columns, no mistakes have been made in programming the code. So I don't understand why I doesn't run the matrix.

Comment: That code produces an error , not a continuation symbol. Voting to close as an  irreproducible behavior report.

Comment: @BondedDust I took "formula" to mean "template" as in that is the general form but when really used they did put data in where needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A prompt of `+` indicates that the code you entered is **incomplete**. I suspect a missing parenthesis.

Here's a full example, first showing this working:

```
mat <- matrix(c(1,2,3,
                4,5,6,
                7,8,9),
              nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE)
mat
```

Which produces

```
> mat <- matrix(c(1,2,3,
+                 4,5,6,
+                 7,8,9),
+               nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE)
> mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    4    5    6
[3,]    7    8    9
```

If, however, you miss off a parenthesis, R will wait for further input:

```
mat <- matrix(c(1,2,3,
                4,5,6,
                7,8,9,                 # missing closing ) on c()
              nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE)
mat
```

which gives:

```
> mat <- matrix(c(1,2,3,
+                 4,5,6,
+                 7,8,9,                 # missing closing ) on c()
+               nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE)
+
```

Now we are at the `+` prompt and R is waiting for input. If I now proceed to type `mat`, we'd get an error as the code now is not syntactically correct:

```
+ mat
Error: unexpected symbol in:
"              nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE)
mat"
```